# Does Ubuntu on the Microsoft Store wipe your system?

Tags: system-installation, windows, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, microsoft

Does installing Ubuntu from the Microsoft Store wipe your PC?

Comment: If it was _that_ destructive Microsoft wouldn't allow it in the store in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

No. Installing Ubuntu from the Microsoft Store in Windows 10 doesn't delete anything or even modify your partitions. Instead, it creates [a WSL Ubuntu system](https://ubuntu.com/wsl), which is part of Windows 10.

You may need to [enable the necessary features of Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) to make this work, but even if you don't, installing Ubuntu through the Microsoft store still does not delete anything.

However, if your goal is to have separate Windows and Ubuntu systems installed on your computer, then this isn't what you want. A WSL system is entirely dependent on, and runs inside, Windows 10.

Comment: Also WSL is just cmdline, even though that is enough to get most of your work done...